# Unable to open a Website using Selenium on Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting multiple error messages for which I tried googling but that did not work.
I've added the Chrome driver in the same directory and tried to code but get a bunch of errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('www.google.com')
```

Errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rajesh.Rao\PycharmProjects\Kofax\salesforce_login.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver.get('www.google.com')
  File "C:\Users\Rajesh.Rao\PycharmProjects\Kofax\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Rajesh.Rao\PycharmProjects\Kofax\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Rajesh.Rao\PycharmProjects\Kofax\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.54)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00BC3AB3+2505395]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B5AE41+2076225]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A62360+1057632]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A550C0+1003712]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A53F39+999225]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A54016+999446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A63A6A+1063530]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AB56ED+1398509]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AA59F3+1333747]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AB5168+1397096]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AA58BB+1333435]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A823E4+1188836]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A8323F+1192511]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4CB36+1554566]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DF4A0C+2242396]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C50E0B+523099]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C4FEB0+519168]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B602FD+2097917]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B64388+2114440]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B644C2+2114754]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B6E041+2154561]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x764CFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C87A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C87A6E+238]
```

Comment: That's not how you can get the driver. You should download it and give the location of the ChromeDriver to it. Like: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe")` Cheers!

Comment: @DineshRoy is right, you have to download chromedriver (check for the right version, according to our chrome) and then put the path in webdriver.Chrome(YOURPATH)

Comment: @DineshRoy I tried your suggestion and did give the location of the path where I had the chromedriver.exe and it still shows the same error with the addition of the below : 

C:\Users\Rajesh.Rao\PycharmProjects\Kofax\salesforce_login.py:2: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:\chromedriverwin32\chromedriver.exe')

Comment: You can try:

`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)`

This should get rid of the error.
You can also try: 
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Drivers/geckodriver.exe")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are looking for auto-upgrade, Please use `chromedriver-autoinstaller`.

Automatically download and install chromedriver that supports the currently installed version of chrome. This installer supports Linux, MacOS and Windows operating systems.

**Installation**

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

**Usage**

Just type `import chromedriver_autoinstaller` in the module you want to use **chromedriver**.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Comment: Thank you.. That did not give any error but now the browser opened, loaded the page and then closed down automatically.. What do we need to do here?

Comment: What do you mean? the code work as it should. You were looking for `driver.get('www.google.com')` and no it works.